# What is the Optimal Ports Loadout for Missionary and Occultist Special Voyages

Tags: runescape

What is the optimal ports load out if I can build any Shipwright, hire any possible crew with any possible traits, have any captain with any possible traits
and generally have everything unlocked for the two following voyages:

The Occultist needs 20480 morale and 20480 combat.

The Missionary needs 20480 combat and 20480 seafaring.

What values would this dream crew be getting in those stats?

Answer (score 1):

The missions for the Occultist and the Missionary are best to be done once you get access to the Hook region and its azure. Regardless, the order of focus is:

1. Crew members
2. Ship upgrades

The shipwright really doesn't matter, its boosts are negligible. But you should focus on combat, as that's the one stat you can't increase as much as the others with ship equipment alone.

Recruit the best crew available to you, and keep swapping your older ones with them. Even if the new ones are initially weaker, they'll level up fast.

Try to aim for four ships; one for combat, one for seafaring, one for morale and one as a combination of all. This way you'll always have enough powerful crew members available for any story mission.